# how to use session in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
        // first page
            <?php
            session_start();
            //   $var_value =$_SESSION['orderidno'];
            //   $var_value =$_GET['orderur'];
               
            
            if(isset($_POST['login']))
            {
                $mobileNo=$_POST['mobileNo'];
                $passWord=$_POST['passWord'];
            }
            
             $curl = curl_init();
            
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
              CURLOPT_URL => 'here is my api url',
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
              CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
              CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
              CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
             
            ));
            
            $response_details = curl_exec($curl);
            $data_details=json_decode($response_details,TRUE);
            $data1_details=json_decode($response_details);
            curl_close($curl);
            
              $res=$data_details['ispasswordMatched'];
               
                if($res)
                {
                    
               $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";
               $_SESSION['loggedinnumber'] = $mobileNo;
               foreach($data_details['content'] as $result)
               {
                    $_SESSION['vendorname'] = $result['vendorname'];
               $_SESSION['vendorkey'] = $result['vendorkey'];
               $_SESSION['userkey'] = $result['key'];
               //here i have been storing my api result values in session
               }
              echo "<script> location.href='userdetails.php'; </script>";
                }
                else if($mobileNo!="")
                {
                    $empty=$data_details['message'];
                }
            ?>
            
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <title>PHP HTML TABLE DATA SEARCH</title>
                    <style>
                        table,tr,th,td
                        {
                            border: 1px solid black;
                        }
                        div#searcharea {
                text-align: center;
            }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
            
            
                        <form id="search_form" method="post"  action="login.php" >
              <!--<h4>Search Customer / Customer Order</h4>-->
              <div>
                <input id="mobilenumbervalue" style="width: 88%; margin-top: 22px" type="text" name="mobileNo" placeholder="Enter the Mobile Number" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required>  
                   <input id="orderidvalue" style="width: 88%; margin-top: 22px" type="password" name="passWord" placeholder="Enter the password"  required>
                <br>
              
                    <p id="mobileError" style="color: red;"><?php echo $empty?></p>
                    <p id="orderError" style="color: red;"><?php echo $emptyOrder?></p>
                
                
              </div>
              <div>
                <Button style="background: #fdd110;      width: 35%;
                height: 39px;   border: #fdd110; margin-top: 15px;" id="userdataSearchButton" type="submit" name="login" >Log In</Button>
              </div>
            </form>
            
                    
                    <script  type="text/javascript">
                    
                    
            function myFunction() {
                alert("work in progress");
            }
            
            
            
            function required()
            {
            var empt = document.forms["form1"]["valueToSearch"].value;
            if (empt == "")
            {
            alert("Please input a Value");
            return false;
            }
            
            }
            </script>
                </body>
            </html>
    //end of first page
        //second page
        //userdetails.php
        <?php
        session_start();
        $var_value =$_SESSION['loggedin'];
        if($var_value!="true")
        {
            echo "the user doesn't exist";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "the user is exists";
        }
        ?>
//here will be my second page html 
    //end of second page
```

### what i am doing

1. In the first part I have been checking the database if the mobile number and password exists .If the mobile number exists then I have been saving them in session to use in another pages and in '$_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true"; setting session as true'.
2. In the second page I have been checking if the user exists by checking if the session is true but the session value is empty.

### Problem

1. In second page I have been checking if its value is true but its value is empty so I can't let user to use the page.
2. All other session value is also empty.

### Description

1. This program was working while I hosting them in godaddy .
2. after I changed to the new server the session is not working like it was working in godaddy

### Working Method

1. If I run these in separate php and call via ajax it is working the session value is 'true' but all my codes are like in first page php, html and javascript all are in single page .
2. I need a solution how to run them in a single page.

### *. This session problem only arise if I use these codes in my new linux server hosting , But in godaddy linux hosting is working fine.

### Comment me if any additional information needed.

Comment: For working with session you have to call session_start(); only in the first row of code. You call it another time in the first page. Try to delete it.

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove while i post the question but i tried with the session_start(); only in first line still its not working

Comment: In the second page, have you check the value for $_SESSION['orderidno']; too? Because, if you have that value in second page,  then you have a problem with login and no with the session.

Comment: I am not getting any value from first page session. But I can get within the first page . If I use "echo $_session['loofedin']" it showing true . But if I use in another page it's showing empty like the session don't have value

Answer (score 0):

Since you experienced a different behaviour in two different ambients, I would check the php configuration in the new server for session handling, that is ['session.cookie_httponly'](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly) (since you use javascript for redirection), ['session.use_cookies'](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies) and ['session.use_only_cookies'](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies).

Besides, I would suggest to force-close the session before doing a redirection, to ensure the session actually writes the data before the new page loads.